# How to improve my glm model, with a lot of potential predictors and millions of observations?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling, feature-selection

I know the question is a bit general but I am a bit stuck.

I am using a glm model with the binomial family to predict if a specific occurrence is going to happen or not. The problem is I have more than 150 potential predictors and millions of observations. I am struggling to improve the model. I an=m using the `p value` to evaluate if a certain predictor should be in the model but I am facing a problem that the most of the predictors have some type of influence because it is such a huge dataset. For now I have been choosing the predictors hierarchically based on my knowledge but the model does not seem to improve, the highest `Veal-Zimmerman pseudo R2` that I got was about 0.08.

Is there a more efficient way to see which of the potential predictors I have the highest predictive power?

Comment: Removing predictors based on p-values is a terribly bad idea, especially if your goal is prediction. You should split your dataset (into training and validation data), use cross-validation with the training data and assess the final predictive performance with the validation data. Why do you need to remove predictors at all? Maybe glmnet could be helpful but you might want to switch to a "proper" machine learning approach.

Comment: the function `stepAIC` from the package MASS automates the process you are describing.

Comment: @Roland I am removing predictors because I want a model with as little of them as possible. What would you use to assess the final model? For now I am using ```AIC``` to assess between the models and ```Veal-Zimmermann pseudo R2``` and ```AUC``` to assess the fit of the model. Yesterday I came across the ```Brier Score``` but I still have to take a closer look into it.

Comment: @Isaiah thanks for your comment, I used also ```stepAIC``` but it just keeps all the predictors I included, as I said, because there are so many observations, the model finds it always somehow significant.